# What happens to transactions sent via old software after hard fork?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, hard-fork

If I am using Monero binaries v0.10.3, and try to send transactions after the hard fork on September 15, 2017, will those transactions just be ignored by miners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the transaction. After the coming hard fork, ring sizes 3 and 4 will be forbidden on the network (bar certain special cases), but that is the main change. If you were to send a transaction with a 0.10.3.1 wallet with a ring size equal or greater to 5, it'd be accepted by a 0.11.0.0 daemon.